# ¿Como uso el IDENT_CURRENT() para saber el ultimo registro modificado en tabla con multiples llaves?

Tags: sql-server, select

La función funciona a la perfección cuando se trata de averiguar el ultimo registro actualizado de una tabla. Pero hasta donde, esta función solo trabaja en tablas con unica clave primaria. ¿Como hago esto mismo pero en una tabla que tiene tres claves primarias? Ya que intento:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Tabla_Multiple_Clave')
```

Y me devuelve una query con un registro en `NULL`

Comment: Lo que entrega `IDENT_CURRENT` es el último valor de una columna **identity**, no tiene que ver con si es llave primaria o no.

Comment: Aun asi necesito que me devuelva las tres claves, para saber exactamente cual fue el ultimo registro modificado. Quiza  `IDENT_CURRENT()` no sea la función indicada para esto, pero debe haber otra, o alguna manera de saberlo.

Comment: Pues no, no hay una función que lo haga, la única forma es si tienes alguna columna que contenga la fecha de inserción/actualización de la fila. O mejor aún sería crear una columna identity de todas formas

Comment: Ojo que en el comentario anterior dijiste `cuál fue el último registro modificado`...`IDENT_CURRENT` sólo entrega el último valor generado para una columna identity, vale decir, sólo el último valor *insertado*, no *actualizado*

Comment: Tenia entendido que para el ultimo valor identity insertado se usaba la funcion `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` , y que para el ultimo modificado era el `IDENT_CURRENT()`. Yo entiendo que este ultimo no me devolvera ningun registro, pero si la clave de dicho registro modificado. La cuestion es que yo necesito que me arroje 3 claves.

Comment: Pues estás confundido con lo que hacen esas funciones, todas entregan el último valor identity generado...pero hay diferencias sobre la sesión ([aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql#remarks) puedes ver la documentación). Como puse en el comentario anterior, no hay una función que entregue directamente lo que estás pidiendo